# Winding number three simple proofs

Tags: complex-analysis

We have $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ a closed curves $[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ and define for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$:
$$
\gamma(t) = \frac{\gamma_1(t) - w}{\gamma_2(t) - w}
$$

We also assume that:
$$
|\gamma_1(t) - \gamma_2(t)| < |w - \gamma_2(t)|, \forall t\in[0,1]
$$
We are to prove three things:

1. $\gamma$ is closed
2. $|1 - \gamma(t)| < 1$. What is $Ind_\gamma(0)$?
3. While calculating $Ind_\gamma(0)$ using definition, see why there must be  $Ind_{\gamma_1}(w) = Ind_{\gamma_2}(w)$

First two were relatively easy, $\gamma$ is closed:
$$
\gamma(0)= \frac{\gamma_1(0) - w}{\gamma_2(0) - w} = \frac{\gamma_1(1) - w}{\gamma_2(1) - w} = \gamma(1)
$$
and since $|1 - \gamma(t)| < 1$:
$$
|1 - \gamma(t)| = |\frac{\gamma_2(t) - w - \gamma_1(t) + w}{\gamma_2(t) - w}| < |\frac{w - \gamma_2(t)}{\gamma_2(t) - w}| = 1
$$
we know the winding of 0 is also 0 (because the distance from 1 to every point on the curve is lesser than 1 so curve never actually winds 0).

I got stuck on third task though.

$$
Ind_\gamma(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w - z}dw
$$
How am I supposed to put the $\gamma$ there? I know that for arbitrary $\gamma$
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_\alpha^\beta f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt
$$

Comment: There must be something missing here. First, if $\gamma_2(t) = w$ for some value of $t$, then $\gamma$ isn't even well-defined. Second if we fix $w = 0$ and let $\gamma_2(t) = exp(2\pi i t)$, and let $\gamma_1(t) = 1.1 \gamma_2(t)$, where $\epsilon(t)$ is any loop in the unit disk, then we have $|\gamma_1(t) - \gamma_2(t)| = |0.1| < 1 = |0 - \gamma_2(t)|$, so the assumed inequality holds. And $\gamma(t)$ is the constant function $1.1$, so $|1 - \gamma(t) = 0.1| < 1$. And yet the conclusion that $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ is false.

Comment: I am sorry for wasting your time, there was a mistake - I am to see why there must be  $Ind_{\gamma_1}(w) = Ind_{\gamma_2}(w)$.

Comment: That's what comments are for -- they're a way to make questions better by clarifying (and getting rid of silly typos). The new formulation makes much more sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 2, there's a possible translation error (it appears that English may not be your native language), or a possible understanding error. I think that in step 2, you are supposed to **prove**, using the definition of $\gamma$ and the *assumption* that 
\begin{align}
|\gamma_1(t) - \gamma_2(t)| < |w - \gamma_2(t)|, \tag{**}
\end{align}
that $|1 - \gamma(t)| < 1$. What you've written almost does this:

We compute:
\begin{align}
|1 - \gamma(t)| 
&= |\frac{\gamma_2(t) - w - \gamma_1(t) + w}{\gamma_2(t) - w}| \\
&< |\frac{\gamma_2(t) - \gamma_1(t)}{\gamma_2(t) - w}|\\
&= \frac{|\gamma_2(t) - \gamma_1(t)|}{|\gamma_2(t) - w|} \\
&< 1
\end{align}
where the final step comes from the the assumption (**).

In the second part of part 2, you've written "(because the distance from 1 to every point on the curve is lesser than 1 so curve never actually winds 0)" which uses the informal idea that the winding number is zero exactly when the curve doesn't "enclose" the point, but it's not really a proof.

To show this part, I think you really need the (unstated) assumption that $\gamma_2(t) \ne w$ for all $0 \le t \le 1$, for otherwise $\gamma$ isn't well-defined. But making that assumption, you're computing
\begin{align}
Ind_\gamma(0) 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w - z}dw \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{w - \gamma(t)} \cdot \gamma'(t) ~ dt \\
\end{align}
Letting $F(z) = Log(w-\gamma(t))$, which is well-defined and analytic because $w - \gamma(t)$ is always in the right half-plane, you can see that this your integral is just 
$$
\int_0^1 (F\circ \gamma)'(t) ~dt = (F\circ \gamma)(1)  - (F\circ \gamma)(0)
$$
which is zero.

For the third part, you asked how to write the index-integral in a way that involves $\gamma$, and I've already done so above:

\begin{align}
Ind_\gamma(0) 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w - z}dw \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{w - \gamma(t)} \cdot \gamma'(t) ~ dt \\
\end{align}

I'm not certain how to go from this integral being 0 to showing that the two other integrals are equal (perhaps something about $log(u/v) = log(u) - log(v)$ might help), but this at least addresses the question you asked about "how to get $\gamma$ in there."